# NHibernate HQL could not locate named parameter [parameterName] error

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am having problems with my HQL query bellow:

```
var merchantTransactions = session.CreateQuery("SELECT MS.Transaction "+
                                               "FROM MerchantSite AS MS "+
                                               "INNER JOIN MS.Transaction AS MST"+
                                               "WHERE MS.Site.Name = :merchantName");
```

Then I set parameters like this:

```
merchantTransactions.SetParameter("merchantName", merchantName);
```

And it gives me a "could not locate named parameter" error, any ideas why?

merchantName does exist in this context and all the table names are correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a space between `MST` and `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use methods to create an HQL statment using a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) style. Try something like this:

```
var merchantTransactions = session.CreateQuery("SELECT MS.Transaction "+
                                               "FROM MerchantSite AS MS "+
                                               "INNER JOIN MS.Transaction AS MST"+
                                               "WHERE MS.Site.Name = :merchantName")
                                  .SetParameter("merchantName", merchantName);
```

Or

```
merchantTransactions = merchantTransactions.SetParameter("merchantName", merchantName);
```

And do not forget to call a method to concrete your query.

```
  var result = merchantTransactions.List<Entity>();
```